# How to create digital object identifier (DOI) for bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, doi

I see that GitHub [has DOI integration through Zenodo](https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/) but is there an equivalent tool for Bitbucket?

Or do I have to contact a [DOI Registration Agency](https://www.doi.org/faq.html) directly?

Answer (score 6):

No. [Support for Zenodo is an open issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12467/zenodo-integration). [Contact was made with Zenodo](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/9448/provide-api-for-adding-hooks) asking for Bitbucket support, but Zenodo said Bitbucket currently lacks the right features in the API.